# Как открыть скрипт в новом окне?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, как прописать этот скрипт, чтобы он открывался в новом окне и не потерял работоспособность.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://widgets.amung.us/map.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">WAU_map('mtyqtwkyseeo', 240, 135, 'textbook', 'star-yellow')</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать js скрипт, который будет запускаться позже скрипта виджета. Этот скрипт будет находить в контенте виджета нужную ссылку и вставлять в нее код открытия в новом окне (например, добавлять target=_blank)

Answer (score 0):

Создаете html страницу, прописываете в ней минимальную структуру и вставляете введенный вами код как есть в body. А потом просто укажите ссылку на новую страницу.

Comment: Этот вариант не подходит. Это сервис отображения посетителей (глобальная карта), стоит в виджете показывает в реальном времени. http://skr-silniy.org/

Comment: Если вам надо, чтобы сам виджет открывал информацию на новых страницах, обратитесь к разработчику виджета, чтобы добавил эту возможность. Потому что это уже не javascript, а flash.

Comment: Да нет же, этот скрипт дают на этом сайте (сервисе), и сам вставляеш себе в виджет или footer или хоть в шапку!! Проблема в том что когда нажимаеш на картинку закрывается мой сайт и открывается сайт сервис. Как сделать что бы этот скрипт открывался в новой вкладке. РАЗВЕ НЕ РЕАЛЬНО!!!

Comment: Я о том и говорю: разработчики виджета не предоставили возможности выбора, как открывать ссылки с карты. Обратитесь к ним - авось, одумаются.